# Conditional span display in table

Tags: reactjs

I'm displaying in a table, several columns with different values. I would like only to show the "spans" in the cells if the value is not empty. I can achieve this with something like this:

```
         <Td>
            <span>
            {claim.state && (
              <span className="d-block"><b>State: </b>{claim.state}</span>)}
            {claim.comment && (
              <span className="d-block"><b>Comment: </b>{claim.comment}</span>)}
            </span>
          </Td>

          <Td>
            <span>
            {claim.something && (
              <span className="d-block"><b>Something: </b>{claim.something}</span>)}
            {claim.another && (
              <span className="d-block"><b>Another: </b>{claim.another}</span>)}
            </span>
          </Td>

          (...)
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient/cleaner way to do it, so I wouldn't have to repeat `{claim.x && (` per span, as there are several columns with several spans + values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make separate component:

```
let SpanRender = ({ data, propName, text }) =>
  data[propName] && (
    <span className="d-block">
      <b>{text} </b>
      {data[propName]}
    </span>
  );
```

Usage:

```
  <SpanRender data={{ name: 'David' }} propName="name" text="Name is" />
```